# XML error (in android)

Tags: android, xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context="gr.uoa.eclass.myapplication.MainActivity">



<TextView

    android:text="Hello World!"

    android:id="@+id/textView" />
```

This is the code, I cant seem to find the error though.
I would appreciate any hints.

Comment: Well, for starters your XML is simply not well-formed. Where's the opening bracket that matches `...MainActivity">`? What error are you seeing and where?

Answer (score 0):

What's the error message ?

try adding a layout as the parent ei:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
```

```
android:text="Hello World!"

android:id="@+id/textView" />
```